# Why is string interning failing here (or is it)?

Tags: c#, string, string-interning

Consider the following C# code:

```
  var a = "123";
  var b = 123.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(a==b);
  Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
  Console.WriteLine("a interned? " + string.IsInterned(a));
  Console.WriteLine("b interned? " + string.IsInterned(b));
  Console.WriteLine(
    ReferenceEquals(
      string.IsInterned(a),
      string.IsInterned(b)
      )
    );
```

This outputs

```
True
False
a interned? 123
b interned? 123
True
```

Everything about this makes sense except why `ReferenceEquals(a,b)` returns false considering `a` got interned and then `b` would refer to `a`, as indicated by the `string.IsInterned` checks.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and Please see this for understanding.

Comment: `123.ToString();` *depends* on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and that's why *can't* be computed at *compile time* (and thus interned)

Comment: @stuartd does not explain the interning part

Comment: It certainly does not explain why the 123 to string is not interned

Comment: ReferenceEquals compares the two strings and are if they both the same string in memory then returns true. IF there are two locations in memory one for a and one for b then this returns false.

Comment: I can't answer that properly since it's now closed but it all comes down to this: 123.toString() is a runtime creation and therefore is not a literal so it is not interned and a new object is created. Same thing would happen with a string builder. The value though that is represented by the new string is interned and that's why the IsInterned returns the value.

Comment: The rules are simple.  What is interned is determined by the compiler, it only picks string literals.  And the rare case where code calls String.Intern() explicitly.  Any string that's generated in code, such as the int-to-string conversion in this case, will not be interned and therefore will be a unique object.  Be sure to compare strings with == or String.Compare() instead of relying on ReferenceEquals().

Comment: @HansPassant but if `123.ToString()` is not interned then `IsInterned()` should have returned `null` and it instead returned the string.

Comment: That's not how IsInterned() works.  It searches the intern table, looking for an interned string with the same value.  Yes, you have one, the "123" literal in your program.  Bit of an accident.